# heroku push rejected no cedar-supported app detected php - index.php present

Tags: php, heroku

I am trying to push my php app to Heroku and get the below error.

Heroku receiving push
 !    Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected.

I have read through all the previous posts which said that the PHP app should have a index.php in the root folder...which i do. When i do a "git ls-files" i get the index.php listed (with the name in lowercase).

steps i have performed so far are.
1. i have an application created on Heroku - stack:Cedar
2. git add the relevant files
3. git commit with a comment
4. git push heroku master -- this guy gives me the error.

git ls-files lists a file "index.php".

What am i missing this time?

Comment: Are you sure the app isn't in a subdirectory or something? I had this problem once with a Rails app.

Comment: @apfel Could you please be a bit more specific as to what you mean by not being in a sub directory? Any command i can use to find/confirm this?

the output of git ls-files is
channel.html
file.txt
images/Background.png
images/BannerText.png
index.php
utils.php

does this help?

Comment: Run `ls -la` and make sure the `.git` directory is in the same folder as the `index.php` file.

Comment: @apfel...that did not work either.

Comment: @apfel... having index.php and .git in same dir did not help 
ls -la gives the output but push gives the same error.
.
..
.DS_Store
.git
.project
ContactUs.html
MyApp.php
PrivacyPolicy.html
Test.html
Themes-backup
channel.html
file.txt
images
index.php
sdk
themes
txt.txt
utils.php

Comment: Well, I don't know what the problem could be then. Maybe contact the Heroku support? It should work regarding their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was with an incorrect/incomplete .git directory. Deleting the old one and recreating it (git init) solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just starting out with Heroku and was encountering the same problem. Below is a description of what I did wrong.

**Procfile**

Make sure that the following statement is included in your `Procfile`:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 path/to/web/
```

Where `path/to/web/` is the relative path to the directory that you want to publicly expose on the web. Make sure that the public directory contains an `index.php` file (e.g. `path/to/web/index.php`).

**composer.json**

In your `composer.json` directory (which should be in the base directory of the repository) make sure to include the Heroku PHP buildpack.

```
{
  "require": {

  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  }
}
```

If this statement was missing, then run `composer update` (`./composer.phar update` for me, because I downloaded composer and placed it in the base directory of my repository) so that Composer will fetch the package and install it into your `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this on you heroku toolbelt

```
> heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
> git add .
> git git commit -am "add composer.json for PHP app detection"
> git push / git push heroku master
```